# .net Maui Store RequestPurchaseAsync();

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code, maui

Is there way to make this Windows.Services.Store method work in .Net MAUI

```
StoreProductResult productResult = await appinfo.GetStoreProductForCurrentAppAsync();
```

When my App reaches RequestPurchaseAsync() it doesnt bring up the Store Sign in Interface. It just awaits forever. All other methods for the Windows Store work except RequestPurchaseAsync()

If I run my code in a Universal Windows App it functions. But im using .net Maui. This is striclty for Windows and i have the code in the Windows Platform section. It is running on the Mainthread as well.

```
 public static async void PurchaseAsync()
        {
      
                StoreContext appinfo = null;
                appinfo = StoreContext.GetDefault();

                StoreProductResult myApp = await appinfo.GetStoreProductForCurrentAppAsync();
                if (productResult.ExtendedError != null)
                {

                    return;
                }


                StoreAppLicense license = await appinfo.GetAppLicenseAsync();
            if (license.IsTrial)
            {

                StorePurchaseResult result = await myApp.Product.RequestPurchaseAsync();
                if (result.ExtendedError != null)
                {

                    return;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is there any log about this problem?

Comment: I cant produce a log file. There is no error it just never goes to the store. Ive searched Google and it always references Unversal Windows. Maui has little support and references.

Answer (score 2):

After 2 weeks of trying to resolve this i have. There is very little sample code for MAUI. I managed to get the Exception Error to trap. It was an "invalid window handle". Have to create a window handle in MauiProgram.cs then IntializeWithWindow.

```
WindowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);

var appinfo = StoreContext.GetDefault();
WinRT.Interop.InitializeWithWindow.Initialize(appinfo, MauiProgram.WindowHandle);     

StorePurchaseResult result = await appinfo.RequestPurchaseAsync(StoreId);
```